# How are multivalued mappings composed?

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces, covering-spaces

As I understand it, there's basically two approaches to multivalued functions. One of them is that a multivalued function $\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is just a relation $\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. This works to some extent, e.g. in the [Gelfond-Schneider theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem) and the explicit solution of the general cubic. However, it seems to be ill-suited for the purposes of calculus, [and naive attempts at fixing these kinds of problems tend to fail](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2274542/can-the-composite-of-two-smooth-relations-fail-to-be-smooth). To solve this issue, I think there's another approach to multivalued functions via covering spaces. Basically, we declare something along the following lines:

> **Definition.** A *multivalued mapping* $\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ consists of a set of isolated points $X \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ together with a holomorphic function $U(\mathbb{C} \setminus X) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, where $U(J)$ is notation for the universal covering space of $J$.

Something like that. I don't know what such things are actually called, but they generalize meromorphic functions (because we're allowing the singularities to be essential). I'll just call them *multivalued mappings* here. Anyway, it seems reasonable that such things should form a ring. I've read that the set of meromorphic functions on a connected domain forms a field, so I suppose that the entities under discussion do, too. Seems to make sense. But here's something I really don't understand:

> **Question.** Is there a sensible way of composing these multivalued mappings, making them into a "partial monoid" or something like that? If so, how is this defined, and which pairs of multivalued mappings are composable?

Comment: A mapping $\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is single-valued. A multi-valued mapping would be e.g. $\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}^{n}$, where $n>1$.